# One table for all transaction VS. Table for each feature

Tags: mysql, database, postgresql

I'm making a website which has to do with money transactions.

Should I have one table to store all transaction history or I should have a seperated table for every feature?

**One table for all**

```
Transactions

user type amount custom_data timestamp
```

**One table for each feature**

```
wire_transfer_transactions

transferFrom(user) transferTo(user) amount timestamp
```

```
charge_transactions

user amount timestamp
```

Answer (score 0):

You generally want one main table for the transactions so there can be a unique transaction ID and an easy way balance all your transaction.  However, you may need a linked detail table to store additional details related to the transaction.

Comment: How can I link table?

Comment: You need to give your main table an ID field, such as TransactionID.  
And then the Detail table that links to the main table still needs a unique id, such as TransactionDetailID, but the detail table will also need the main TransactionID.  Then you link the tables with the TransactionID field.

Comment: If you are a beginner and building a relatively simple system with only one form of payment per transaction, then it would be fine to just put all the transaction details in one table.